# How to count the number of orders and the number of returns from same order id?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to derive a table as CustomerID, OrderCount and ReturnCount from a table with columns as `CustomerID`, `OrderID`, `ReturnFlag`

I've tried the following code that gives me 2 distinct tables but I want the results in a single output table.

```
select "CustomerID", count(DISTINCT "OrderID") as OrderCount  
from "Customer" 
group by "CustomerID";

select "CustomerID", count(DISTINCT "OrderID") as ReturnCount 
from "Customer" 
where "ReturnFlag" = 1 
group by "CustomerID";
```

Source Table -

```
|CustomerID| |OrderID| |ReturnFlag|
|1     | |  A    | |    0 |
|2     | |   B   | |        1 |
|1     | |  C    | |    0 |
|2     | |   D   | |    0 |
|3     | |   E   | |    1 |
```

Expected output table -

```
|CustomerID| |OrderCount| |ReturnCount|
|1     | |  2      | |  0     |
|2     | |  2      | |        1  |
|3     | |  1      | |  1     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
select "CustomerID",
       count(DISTINCT "OrderID") as OrderCount,
       count(DISTINCT case when "ReturnFlag" = 1 then "OrderID" end) as ReturnCount
from "Customer"
group by "CustomerID";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select "CustomerID",
        count(DISTINCT case when "ReturnFlag" = 1 THEN "OrderID" end) as ReturnCount 
        count(DISTINCT "OrderID") as OrderCount 
from "Customer" 
group by "CustomerID";
```

I am a little baffled why `CustomerID` would not be unique in a table called `Customer`.  I would expect this query to be run on the `Orders` table, not the customers table.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL.

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select "CustomerID", 
       count(DISTINCT "OrderID") as OrderCount, 
       count(DISTINCT "OrderID") filter (where "ReturnFlag" = 1) as return_count
from "Customer" 
group by "CustomerID";
```

If your DBMS does not support the standard `filter()` clause you can use a case expression:

```
select "CustomerID", 
       count(DISTINCT "OrderID") as OrderCount, 
       count(DISTINCT case when "ReturnFlag" = 1 then "OrderID" end) as return_count
from "Customer" 
group by "CustomerID";
```